# Is there a way to get the value of a variable, the name of which is contained in another variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

Here is the question in code terms:

```
declare @v1 int=100
declare @v2 int=200
declare @v3 int=300
declare @name_of_var_I_need nvarchar(max)='@v2'

select some_function_or_other_trick(@name_of_var_I_need)
```

> output: 200

This seemingly simple question is evading me. I cannot use dynamic sql, because variables do not go through the different session.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. Please see [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84180/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-variables-in-a-dynamic-sql-which-is-declared-outs)

Comment: If there is a small, known set of variables of compatible types you can use the inelegant `case @name_of_var_I_need when '@v1' then @v1 when '@v2' then @v2 when '@v3' then @v3 else 42 end`. That's assuming you need the value of the variable. If you want to set the value, i.e. use the variable variable as a left-hand-side in an assignment, then `if`/`else` is about as good as it gets. An alternative for getting the value would be putting all the variables in a `values` clause and selecting the correct column or row depending on the organization of the `values`.

Comment: I was thinking to make a table var and put all names and values inside, but because my need is one-use, the values table is a great idea, thanks!